# cannot select the item in the dropdownlist, if the list has only one item

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 dropdownlists, the 1st dropdownlist is bind to the second dropdownlist. If the second dropdownlist has only one item, this item cannot be selected and hence any function cannot be triggered. I went to any related answers that have already been uploaded...but it didn't help... It's important. Can someone help me out in this issue?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried? (Code is our bread and butter after all)

Comment: You mean the item is already selected by default so you can't change it, right? In such case you can manually execute its OnChange event from within Page_Load - checking you are not inside PostBack of course.

Comment: I meant its has only one item and that item cannot be selected.              <asp:DropDownList ID="ASSET_LIST1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="True" >
<asp:ListItem Text="---Choose One Asset---"/></asp:DropDownList>

Comment: I think the first one is not actually populating anything for the second dropdown, which i presume is the issue ! !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a default ListItem to your second dropdown.

Eg.

```
<asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
```

You can add from c# also: Write this after you have populated dropdownlist from your datasource.

```
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "-1"));
```

Comment: This options i have already tried and its not working. can u pls suggest me any other option?                                              SqlDataAdapter mydat = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Location_Asset_Master WHERE Location_Name ='" + LOC_LIST2.SelectedItem.Value + "'", con);
            DataSet dset2 = new DataSet();
            mydat.Fill(dset2, "Table");
            ASSET_LIST1.Items.Clear();    My back end code looks something like tis

Comment: Woah...Thank u very much...Its worked awesome and fantastic.... I am very new to C#....may it be a small problem but its lik crazy...thanks again

Answer (score 2):

> this item cannot be selected and hence any function cannot be
>   triggered

This item can't be selected, as its already selected. Therefore your `onchange` event etc, won't be triggered as its not being changed.

You have 2 options:

1. Use [@Kapil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11951214/370103)'s suggestion of adding a "default" item, so that the 2nd item can be selected.
2. Call the same function `onload` as well as `onchange`. Therefore when the page loads the cascaded dropdown will be populated as well:

.

```
protected void Page_Load(){
   BindCascadeDropDown();
}

protected void ddl_onchange() {
   BindCascadeDropDown();
}

protected void BindCascadeDropDown(){
   //Bind here
}
```